# Safe trackable links from 301 redirect

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

I want to create a something where a user can submit a link (http://www.example.com?key=value) then be returned with a new link which will redirect to the link provided in a way that is traceable. (http://trackedlink.com/[trackid]).

I was thinking about adding a get value to the end of the link redirect eg, http://www.example.com?key=value&trackid=[trackid]

My concern is that although extremely unlikely this may override an already set get value (trackid). Is there any truely safe way to do this?

Comment: check of trackid exists first

Comment: Then make it even less likely, e.g. `&trackid0123808a080dsfsdf=123`.